# Is it correct to say "ça c'est..."?

Tags: grammaire, presentation

I remember seeing in an exercise in a French course book the expression "Ça c'est mon portable". That has led me to believe that whenever I wanted to say "This is..." I should use "Ça c'est...". However, when reading other books and watching movies I've seen several instances where a character would simply say "C'est..." to mean "This is...".

What is "Ça c'est" used for? Does it translate directly into "That, it's..."?

Comment: Also see https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45429. There, the point is that you want to say "that" instead of "it" in English, to emphasise strong feelings about a subject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Ça* is used to emphasize whatever *ce* represents.

#### 1

> C'est mon portable.

I simply designate my mobile phone.

#### 2

> Ça, c'est mon portable

(please note the coma after *ça*)

I emphasize that the object (I'm probably pointing at it while I say that) I'm talking about is not my book but my mobile, or that it is not someone else's mobile, but mine.