# "Ça est un plaisir": Why no elision?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

In *Astérix et les Goths*, there is a moment where the characters meet up with a druid deep in a forest who is old friends with a member of their party, who introduces him to the rest. The druid says *Ça est un plaisir!*

Normally I believe this would be *C'est un plaisir.* What tone or inflection of meaning is conveyed by the lack of elision?

Comment: Excellent question. In some of the other plates, that druid has an unusual speaking pattern. For example _"Mangez ces herbes s'il te plaît..."_. This makes him sound like he's from a distant region with its own dialect. _"Ça est"_ could imply that this dialect has fewer elisions, but I don't know how accurate that is with regard to history of French language in Belgium.

Comment: Laure mentions the more typical "Ça, c'est" in [this answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9033/is-it-correct-to-say-%C3%A7a-cest), but that's of course not the same as far as the elision goes. (And not that "Ça, c'est un plaisir" works anyway.)

Comment: It isn't a matter of elision as *ça* is not elided (*ça arrive*, *ça évite*, etc.). The difference is *ce* vs *ça*.

Comment: Okay, but then same final question for "C'est vs Ça est" -- what tone or inflection of meaning is conveyed? I mean, you say that as if it were perfectly common and normal to say *ça est*, but I have almost never encountered it by comparison to *c'est*.

Comment: Isn't that the same druid who demos his way to get fries out of boiling oil with his hands without burning himself?  Still playing on Belgian stereotypes?

Comment: I looked through the fat druid's speeches in the book, he does that Ça est thing three times. So, the authors probably did it on purpose. Normally, it would be; "Ça c'est [whatever]. That pattern is very frequent in French. It does not convey meaning; it is just an odd speech pattern. Maybe suggesting he is a Flemish speaker/? I have no idea. But it's the only odd feature in his speech. No French speaker would ever say that.

Comment: Ok, I had not realized there was an explanation re this from the Grévisse. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's on purpose, to make the druid sound like he is speaking a dialect. So, it is not standard French, but they use it here so that the reader is put in the position of Astérix and Obélix hearing a strange but mutually understandable dialect.

Comment: D'après Laure dans un commentaire à [cette qustion](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/cest-in-pass%c3%a9-compos%c3%a9), Grevisse signale « ça est » comme populaire et plus employé en Belgique, désuet en France.

Comment: Absolutely. Take a look at "Astérix chez les Belges"/"Astérix in Belgium" and you will find several use of "Ca est".